# What's this plant with long black seed pods?

Tags: identification

I just took over an allotment and in it there's this plant that has long black pods that contain what appear to be seeds.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say because of pictures. But maybe it is [*Vicia sativa* subsp. *nigra* (L.) Ehrh.](http://navarraenflorymas.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/vicia-sativa-l-subsp-nigra-l-ehrh-v.html). This plant is present in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at the picture, but its pretty hard to tell for sure what it is, the leaves are sort of buried in with lots of other foliage, mostly grass by the looks of it. Most likely its one of the [Baptisias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptisia) though.

Comment: There were three pictures but someone changed it so that now there's only one.

Comment: @victoriah That was me, my bad. Fixed now.

Comment: @victoriah - the addition of the other two pics doesn't really help, its just a closer view of a tangled mess of leaves, can't tell which belong to the plant and which don't.

Comment: @victoriah - can you cut off one of the stems, with a good number of leaves, and post a photo of that? Unless you're sure its one of the plants suggested in this thread.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, I'll go back to the allotment tomorrow and take a better picture.

Comment: @victoriah a picture of a bean split open (view of seeds) would help also.